# AngularJS Link function not being called

Tags: angularjs

For some reason my link function inside my directive is not being called. I can see that my directive is called with a `console.log` but not the link function.  Also don't mind the controller parameter I will be using that with my parent directive. I have also tried restrict: 'E' with no luck as well. I am not using it for this example. Not sure what is causing it to skip link. Any thoughts?

```
module FormTest {
    angular
        .module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
        .directive('jiTab', function () {
            console.log('directive was hit');
            function linkFn(scope, ele, attrs, controller) {
                console.log('Link is called');
            };
            return {
                require: '^ji-Tabset',
                restrict: 'C',
                transclude: true,
                link: linkFn
            }
        });
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<ji-form name="Main Form">  
    <ji-tabset name="Tabs">  
        <ji-tab tab-name="General"></ji-tab>  
        <ji-tab tab-name="Stats"></ji-tab>  
    </ji-tabset>  
</ji-form>
```

**Parent directive**

```
module FormTest {
    angular
        .module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
        .directive('jiTabset', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: 'FormTest/views/ji-Tabset.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    var tabPanelItems = $scope.tabPanelItems = [];
                    $scope.tabSettings = {
                        dataSource: tabPanelItems
                    }
                }
            };
        });
}
```

Comment: have link function as `var linkFn` while declaring. have you tried this thing?

Comment: function var linkFn? or link: var linkFn?

Comment: like this `var linkFn = function (scope, ele, attrs, controller) {
        console.log('Link is called');
    };`

Comment: My mistake, as soon as I typed that last reply I realized what you meant.  I went ahead and tried that but still not seeing anything in console.

Comment: Can you post the markup where you're using this directive?

Comment: does it showing any console error @Tim

Comment: i think you have problem with your `require: '^ji-Tabset'`

Comment: I have included some more code including the markup in original post.

Comment: I am not currently seeing any errors in output.  Just the log where it shows my directive was hit

Comment: What kind of problem with require: '^ji-Tabset' might you be referring to?  The syntax of how it's being required or the actual ji-Tabset directive itself?

Comment: To complicate things more.....This works if I do a console.log inside a post link function in a compile.  But not if I just put it in link....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
module FormTest {
    angular
        .module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
        .directive('jiTab', function () {
            console.log('directive was hit');
            function linkFn(scope, ele, attrs, controller) {
                console.log('Link is called');
            };
            return {
                require: '^ji-Tabset', //<-- this must be `^jiTabset` read mistake 1
                restrict: 'C', //<-- this must be `E` which stands for element, (jiTab) C is for class, read mistake 2
                transclude: true,
                link: linkFn
            }
        });
 }
```

From docs

## Mistake 1

Normalization
Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

The normalization process is as follows:

- Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
- Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

## Mistake 2

The restrict option is typically set to:

- 'A' - only matches attribute name
- 'E' - only matches element name
- 'C' - only matches class name
  These restrictions can all be combined as needed:

'AEC' - matches either attribute or element or class name

## Mistake 3

You dont have `ng-transclude` attribute in your `jiTabset` directive, make sure you have it there `'FormTest/views/ji-Tabset.html'`

## Worknig demo

*Open browser console*

```js
angular.module('FormTest', []);
angular.module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
        .directive('jiTabset', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                replace: true,
                template: '<div>ji-tabset<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    var tabPanelItems = $scope.tabPanelItems = [];
                    $scope.tabSettings = {
                        dataSource: tabPanelItems
                    }
                }
            };
        });
angular.module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
        .directive('jiTab', function () {
            function linkFn(scope, ele, attrs, controller) {
                console.log('Link is called');
            };
            return {
                require: '^jiTabset',
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                link: linkFn
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="FormTest">
  <ji-form name="Main Form">  
    <ji-tabset name="Tabs">  
        <ji-tab tab-name="General"></ji-tab>  
        <ji-tab tab-name="Stats"></ji-tab>  
    </ji-tabset>  
</ji-form>
</div>
```

Comment: Good catch on mistake 1! Mistake 2 I did have set to 'E' but changed to 'C' because someone in this post thought I should try it.  I have  changed it back to 'E' for since I am only using Element.  Now for results.....I am still just hitting my directive and not my link function.  I am guessing there is a Mistake 3 and 4 somewhere along the way :P

Comment: Thank you that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

By assigning a variable to a function and calling it where ever you want by its variable name,

```
angular
.module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
.directive('jiTab', function () {
 var linkFn = function (scope, ele, attrs, controller) {
    console.log('Link is called');
};
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    transclude: true,
    link: linkFn
}
});
```

by this way i think you can achieve i hope.

Comment: var linkFn = function() === function linkFn()

Comment: In Javascript `var linkFn = function()` and `function linkFn()` do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the link function must live outside the directive ITSELF?

Try this:

```
       module FormTest {

       angular
       .module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
       .directive('jiTab', function () {
           console.log('directive was hit');
           return {
               require: '^jiTabset',
               restrict: 'E',
               transclude: true,
               link: linkFn
           }
       });

       function linkFn(scope, ele, attrs, controller) {
           console.log('Link is called');
       };
     }
```

Comment: This should work because of javascript hoisting. http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: Yes, but there is no need to polute the global scope

Comment: You are right, but OP is not asking about global scopes here. I think best practices state modules should be sorrounded with `(function () { .... })` I will edit the answer. This is mainly for minification purposes - if I recall. Let's focus on the question.

Comment: None the less, it was worth a shot, however I am still not getting "Link is called" in the directive.  But I do agree with swordf1zh that we shouldn't have to polute the global scope by doing this.  I have seen plenty of cases where link works just fine being defined inside the directive

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky I just tried you edited answer. And not only did it not work, but I am not hitting this directive anymore.

Comment: In your case, I believe you have to add the `module FormTest {...}` inside. I modified the answer.

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky Unfortunately when I try that I get an error on "module" at module FormTest {.  The error says "Statement expected".  But when you first posted your example I had module FormTest outside and then your (function () {...}) inside the module FormTest { and that worked but same result in the console.log except "the directive was hit" is gone

Comment: I am a little surprised - but ok. Try it now - I removed my outer code - lets get this to work and then worry about global scope.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, -1

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using the directive as an element so you must change the restrict property value to 'E'.
2. There is no controller in jiTabSet directive so there is no need to require this directive in the jiTab directive. More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

> When a directive uses this option (`require`), $compile will throw an
>   error unless the specified controller is found. The ^ prefix means
>   that this directive searches for the controller on its parents
>   (without the ^ prefix, the directive would look for the controller on
>   just its own element).

Update your directive like this:

```
.directive('jiTab', function () {
    console.log('directive was hit');
    function linkFn(scope, ele, attrs) {
        console.log('Link is called');
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: linkFn
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree.  That is how I had it originally.  I went back and changed it (literally copy and pasted your example) and the only thing in console is: "directive was hit"

Comment: but there is a controller on ji-tabset directive... and when I use $compile with post-link instead of $link the controller is found and I get a console output.  I don't get it.  What my understanding was is that $link can replace post-link

Comment: Yes you are right. When I remove the `transclude: true` of the parent directive it works for me, but not sure why yet.

Comment: are you getting the link function's console log to appear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88035/discussion-between-swordf1zh-and-tim).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have marked an answer above as solution. Issue is resolved